# Create a List of objects in a inner class in one shot

Tags: c#, list

I have two objects:

```
public class DPMenu
{
    private String menuDescription;
    private List<DPMenuItem> menuItems = new List<DPMenuItem>(4);   // Initialize list with 4 items

    public DPMenu(String menuHeader)
    {
        menuDescription = menuHeader;
    }

    public String Description
    {
        get { return menuDescription; }
        set { menuDescription = value; }
    }

    public List<DPMenuItem> MenuItems
    {
        get { return menuItems; }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class DPMenuItem
{
    private String itemDescription;
    private String itemActionLink;

    public String Description
    {
        get { return itemDescription; }
        set { itemDescription = value; }
    }

    public String Link
    {
        get { return itemActionLink; }
        set { itemActionLink = value; }
    }
}
```

Can I create in one shot an object DPMenu populating the inner list?
For example

```
List<DPMenu> mainMenu = new List<DPMenu>();
DPMenu menuHeader;

List<DPMenuItem> menuItems = new List<DPMenuItem>() {
    new DPMenuItem { Description = "A", Link = "A" },
    new DPMenuItem { Description = "B", Link = "B" }
};

menuHeader = new DPMenu("HD").MenuItems.AddRange(menuItems);
```

But it doesn't work...
Thank you!

Comment: Can't you have a constructor overload that accepts `IEnumerable<MenuItem>` ?

Comment: By the way, your last line won't work because you are assigning `menuHeader` what `AddRange` returns, and it returns nothing (`void`). You would need to call `AddRange` in a separate line, or create a constructor that accepts the list.

Comment: Yes I know... but I was not able to figure out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep it simple and just create another overloaded constructor?

```
public DPMenu(String menuHeader, List<DPMenuItem> itemList)
{
    menuDescription = menuHeader;
    menuItems = itemList;
}
```

Once that is done, just have your code do the following. Not sure what you're trying to do, but hope this helps.

```
  List<DPMenuItem> menuItems = new List<DPMenuItem>() {

                new DPMenuItem { Description = "A", Link = "A" },
                new DPMenuItem { Description = "B", Link = "B" }
  };
  menuHeader = new DPMenu("HD", menuItems);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. My goal was to create the object and populate  the internal list in the most compact way possible. It was a bit of a challenge. It is corrected as a practice the structure of the object? Thank you

Comment: @robyg72, Didn't get you when you said "It is corrected as a practice the structure of the object? "

Comment: Also, could you mark this as the answer if correct.